# The French Newbie and the Lotka-Voltera Crazy Idea

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, biology

I am back to talk with you and to have criticisms on ideas crossing my mind!

I am currently working on a disease that is striking french vineyards really hard. I am currently using a model that is working pretty well which is this one.

$S′= −qS(pI+ϵ)^2+k_1I+k_4G$

$I′= qG(pI+ϵ)^2−k_1I−k_3I$

$G′= −qG(pI+ϵ)^2−k_4G+τ_{−1}(D−S−I−G)$

However, I do want to replace the constant p, which stands for pesticides, by a variable varying in time. Basically, p can take every value between 0 and 1, 0 represents a state in which the pesticide is eradicating all the studied insects and 1 represents a state in which the substance is ineffective.

So I had the idea to model p like this:

$p = \dfrac{(p_{O} + p_{NO})}{2}$

to integrate the fact that both organic pesticides and synthetic pesticides are being used. With O standing for organic and NO for non-organic.

$p = \dfrac{\dfrac{Area_O}{Area_T}*e_O + \dfrac{Area_{NO}}{Area_T}*e_{NO}}{2}$

with $e_O$ the effectiveness of the non-organic pesticide and $e_{NO}$ the effectiveness for non-organic one.

So, my first question is : Does it make sense to model the general effectiveness like this ?

$E = 1 - p$

with $p$ the expression above

Furthermore, I don't want $Area_O$ or $Area_{NO}$ to be constants. So, I tried to figure out a way to make them varying in a dependent way. Here come the Competitive Lotka–Volterra equations.

I tried to imagine my two types of areas, O and NO, as two species competing for a ressource which is the soil. This ressource is finite so that $A_T = A_O + A_{NO} = 80$.

Then I first came up with this system of ODE with:

$A'_O = \alpha A_O - \beta A_{NO}$

$A'_{NO} = \beta A_{NO} - \alpha A_{O}$

And therefore :

$A'_O = \beta A_{NO} - \alpha A_{NO}$ + $A_T$ ( $\alpha$ - $\beta$ )$

$A'_{NO} = \alpha A_{NO} - \beta A_{O}$ + $A_T$ ( $\beta$ - $\alpha$ )$

I used ODE45 to simulate it using $\alpha = 0.09$ and $\beta = 0.001$.
It gave me this :

[image]

Of course I am not happy with it because, even if there is the symmetry that I need, it doesn't have a logistic form. In fact, I would like the blue curve to be convergent toward $80$ and the orange one to be convergent toward $0$.

Therefore, I tried to look for the competitive Lotka–Volterra equation, which integrate the logistic dimension, but I am not sure if it is the right path to take.

What do you think about that ? Do you have suggestions on these ideas or criticisms ?

Thanks you all,

Have a good day or a good night,

Hugo

Comment: I cannot seem to grasp why modelling different types of pesticides as competing species works here. Why would the effectiveness of one pesticide ramp up compared to the other one and vice versa? If they do not interact chemically with one another, wouldn't it make more sense to model them as simple decaying exponentials (or some other phenomenological function that decays as $t\to\infty$? Which aspect of the phenomenon is this model of the pesticides attempting to capture?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning for the variables (and parameters) in your equations?

Comment: I find another way using another method ! Thanks you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a different notation for the  variables, just to avoid typing subscripts and Greek letters.

If $X$ is organic and $Y$ is nonorganic  and if $X+Y=80$ then you can get a single differential equation for either one, say $X$.

If the original two-variable model is written as

$X'= mX-nY$ and $Y'=-mX+nY$

then the single model for $X$ is $X'=mX -n (80-X) = (m+n)X-80n$.
The solution should look logistic. The variable $X$ tends to the equilibrium value $X= \frac{80n}{m+n}$ and by a similar argument $y$ approaches the complementary equilibrium value.

P.S. I think the difficulties you had can be traced to algebra errors, since the signs of some of your terms seem backwards.